# Fanuc Robot "Heat" control

Tags: industrial-robot

My work has an older Fanuc robot ( Arc Mate 100-iBe RJ3iB, Fanuc AWE2 teach pendant with  Powerwave 355M) and the old operator/programmer has left. I have taken over his job and cant find out how to turn down the voltage and wire feed speed because it occasionally burns through parts. I tried manually putting in voltage and wire feed speed but it seems it will only accept the previous weld schedules 1-8 and if i mess with them that will affect other programs using those. I just need someone to please point me in the right direction. 
P.S. Typed on phone , sorry if sloppy.

Comment: Please edit question and specify model numbers of controller and welder